# How can I add multiple rooms to my socket.io project?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building a video conferencing application to learn about Node.js and socket.io. So far I have all of the features I want working, except I need to be able to have more than one room.

I have followed several different tutorials and instructions from other StackOverflow posts for doing this, but I can't get it to work. I would like to be able to have multiple instances of the same room. For example: http://localhost:3000/testroom4

Based on the way my code is here, how could I go about getting this functionality in there?

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
let clients = 0

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on("NewClient", function () {
        if (clients < 2) {
            if (clients == 1) {
                this.emit('CreatePeer')
            }
        }
        else
            this.emit('SessionActive')
        clients++;
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you try [https://socket.io/docs/rooms/](https://socket.io/docs/rooms/) ?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, yes I did. But I found it to be a little verbose like most documentation. I followed it without success. :(